# Finding letters of a string in another string

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to find the letter of a string in another string but ONLY using recursion

I have done the following but every time I type something just like "The people are angry" and I want to find the letters "pope" I get false and not true.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
    String s1 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter the letter to if they are in the first string");
    String s2 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(myContains(s2, s2));

}

public static boolean myContains(String s1, String s2){
    if(s1 == null || s2 == null)
        return false;
    if(s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty())
        return false;
    if(s2.startsWith(s1))
        return true;
    return myContains(s1, s2.substring(1));
}
```

//  I just need it to return true when the letter can be found in order in the other string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

How you have the code currently written, returning false is correct. This is because you are currently asking the code that if s2 ("Pope") begins with the following characters from s1 ("The people are angry"), which it is going to return false. After that if statement fails, it makes a sub-string of s2, which would be "ope" after the first run. It will continue like this until s2 is empty and then the system returns false. I recommend you look at the javadocs for how [String.startsWith()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) functions.

### The Solution

You would want to look at the individual characters that make up both the sentence and the string that you are looking for.

```
public static boolean myContains(String s1, String s2) {

    if (s1 == null || s2 == null)
        return false;

    /*  This should be your win condition without adding any more parameters to the method
     *  If it reaches this line, it means one of two things.
     *  1) That s2 is an empty string, in which case s1 will off course contain it.
     *  or
     *  2) That s2 has matched all of its characters with s1, 
     *  and consequently has been sub-stringed till it was empty. 
     */
    if (s2.isEmpty())
        return true;

    /*  If s1 is empty, then it means that the program has looked through all of the char's in it
     *  and has not been able to match all of s2.
     */
    if (s1.isEmpty())
        return false;

    /*  Here, we want to examine if the sentence starts with the first char of the letters
     *  If it does, then we will recursively call the function
     *  and remove the first char in both strings with the substring function.
     */
    if (s1.charAt(0) == s2.charAt(0))
        return myContains(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1));

    /* Finally, if the code as made it down here, we should move the sentence down one letter.
     * However we don't want to progress the letters string, as there was no match
     */
    return myContains(s1.substring(1), s2);

}
```

Now when I ran this code with s1 equaling "The people are angry" and s2 equaling "pope" it returned true.

Comment: thanks that is much clearer now I also realized that in my driver I also had the parameters matching therefore also causing an error